# Spring Boot app is not able to publish events to Kafka in Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Hello fellow programmers!

I am learning Docker and Kafka, and would be very grateful for any help. The problem is that the application is able to connect to Kafka, but not to publish any events. Error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for wages-local-0:120001 ms has passed since batch creation
```

This problem arises when Spring Boot app in one Docker container tries to publish to Kafka in other container:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  publisher_app:
    build:
      context: ./kafka-publisher
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"
    environment:
      kafka.wages-topic.bootstrap-address: kafka:9092
    links:
      - kafka:kafka
```

Here is the link to source code: https://github.com/aleksei17/springboot-rest-kafka-mysql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: are you able to ping to that container from your host ? This appears to be an issue with networking in docker container. follow below link for the solution:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: `kafka.wages-topic.bootstrap-address` does not look like an environment variable

Comment: This is a variable from application.yml and it is used here: https://github.com/aleksei17/springboot-rest-kafka-mysql/blob/master/kafka-publisher/src/main/java/ee/aleksei/gvozdev/kafka/WagesTopicPublisherProperties.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that I needed to delete containers after usage. When I did so, I got an error when starting Kafka container like: `unknown listener PLAINTEXT`. So I changed PLAINTEXT to INTERNAL, and it worked! Here is the final version of docker-compose for Kafka:

```yaml
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

It would be great if it worked both for Dockerized apps and for apps run on the same host outside Docker, but this is a different story. Played with this tutorial, but no success so far: https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-docker-connection

Comment: You only have one listener and one broker, and PLAINTEXT is the built-in, so you don't need a mapping or inter-broker listener

Answer (score 0):

Your config is hard-coded to use `localhost:9092`

You want to [externalize the config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) like so (remove your `kafka.wages-topic` section since bootstrap servers are not a topic-specific setting)

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
```

Then in Compose,

```
environment:
  BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
```

To configure topics, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems there are no problem with `localhost:9092`, because this is overwritten in docker-compose by `kafka.wages-topic.bootstrap-address`.
I would prefer to leave application.yml so that running from IntelliJ is easier

Comment: You can add environment variables to IntelliJ Run Configurations to make it work in both situations